# Python objects lose state after every request in nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, wsgi, gunicorn

This is really troublesome for me. I have a telegram bot that runs in django and python 2.7. During development I used django sslserver and everything worked fine. Today I deployed it using gunicorn in nginx and the code works very different than it did on my localhost. I tried everything I could since I already started getting users, but all to no avail. It seems to me that most python objects lose their state after each request and this is what might be causing the problems. The library I use has a class that handles conversation with a telegram user and the state of the conversation is stored in a class instance. Sometimes when new requests come, those values would already be lost. Please has anyone faced this? and is there a way to solve the problem quick? I am in a critical situation and need a quick solution

Comment: gunicorn uses the prefork worker model. Prefork. Meaning you have a bunch of forked-off **independent processes**. Independent, meaning they have their own state, and don't share memory with each other. If you didn't build your system to have a way to communicate with a central store (redis, &c), then you're going to need to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: @ Charles Duffy, I do have a database but the library I'm using just seems to be saving state. Moreover, I didn't know this about gunicorn

Comment: For the moment, you might turn the worker count down to 1. It'll hurt performance, but better that than having a service that doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, thanks, I'll try that :)

Comment: @Charles Duffy, wow that did it!, I had 3 workers, well I'm ready for performance to go down by a factor of 3 instead of a service that does not work. Thanks, man. You can write an official answer and I will mark as answer:)

Comment: @Ken that's a handy workaround but by no mean a serious solution. You need to persist states into a shared storage (relational db or whatever) so you can use more than one single process (and more than one single server etc), handle process restart etc...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, like I said, it's part of the library I use, not my code. So, I can't do anything in this case. I have my own database where I store stuff, but I can't modify their code

Comment: If you have the source code (which is usually the case with Python) then yes you can modify it. And even if there are licence issues you can at least monkeypatch it one way or another.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, Yeah, I looked into it and it will require several modifications. I'm just hosting a bot, it's not worth it. Moreover, with the hardware I'm hosting the code on, I was told 3-4 workers would be the maximum if I don't want to overload and crash the server. So, I will just stick with one worker for now. I have submitted the issue to the library developers. If they're able to do something themselves, good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gunicorn has a preforking worker model -- meaning that it launches several independent subprocesses, each of which is responsible for handling a subset of the load.

If you're relying on internal application state being consistent across all threads involved in offering your service, you'll want to turn the number of workers down to 1, to ensure that all those threads are within the same process.

---

Of course, this is a stopgap -- if you want to be able to scale your solution to run on production loads, or have multiple servers backing your application, then you'll want to be modify your system to persist the relevant state to a shared store, rather than relying on content being available in-process.